# Making an update on mysql with javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm making some inserts in my BD mysql, but the console is returning me a problem with the syntax of mysql.

```
async postCompletedetails(req, res) {
  const company = req.params.company;
  const name = req.params.name;
  const password = req.params.password;

  bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
    // Now we can store the password hash in db.
  });

  if (
    company !== undefined &&
    name !== undefined &&
    password !== undefined
  ) {

    const {
      token
    } = req.headers;
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION);
    const {
      id
    } = decoded;

    const update = await pool.query(
      `UPDATE user SET Name_user= '${name}', password= '${password}' WHERE ID_user = ${id}`
    );
    const insertid = await pool.query(
      `INSERT INTO rel_company_user (ID_user)  VALUES ${id}`
    );
    const incompany = await pool.query(
      `INSERT INTO company (Name_company) VALUES '${company}' `
    );
    const inrelcompany = await pool.query(
      `INSERT INTO rel_company_user (ID_company, ID_user) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ${id})`
    );

    return res.json({
      code: 200,
      message: "todo bien... todo correcto y yo que me alegro",
      password,
    });
  } else {
    return res.json({
      code: 400,
      message: "Bro hiciste algo mal",
    });
  }
}
```

error from console:

```
(node:9892) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '36' at line 1
```

36 is correct, that user actually exist in My BD, so I don't have an idea what's syntactically wrong

I have a solution, I was declaring the id like an object, but the right is declared it in this method = const id = decode.id
with that, I have the value, but now I have the next error:

```
node:16032) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`kiraldb`.`rel_company_user`, CONSTRAINT `rel_company_user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_company`) REFERENCES `company` (`ID_company`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

It is for the first insert

Comment: Remove extra `,` from `, WHERE`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Which of these lines is the problematic one? Have you dumped the query to see whether this problem is in any way connected to Javascript?

Comment: @NicoHaase is the first update, for some reason is not making the consult, the vars are fine and the consult works on MySQL

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I made the changes

Comment: @NicoHaase ok I have a solution, I was declaring the id like an object, but the right is declared it in this method = const id = decode.id
with that, I have the value, but now I have the next error, check on update

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection. You should use queries with placeholders, not template literals.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the lack of brackets after values. Values is called like

```
VALUES(${id})
```

Where you have:

```
VALUES ${id}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async postCompletedetails(req, res) {
    const company = req.params.company;
    const name = req.params.name;
    const password = req.params.password;

    bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
      // Now we can store the password hash in db.
    });

    if (
      company !== undefined &&
      name !== undefined &&
      password !== undefined
    ) {
        
    const { token } = req.headers;
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION);
    const id = decoded.id;

      const update = await pool.query(
        `UPDATE user SET Name_user= '${name}', password= '${password}' WHERE ID_user = ${id}`
      );
      const incompany = await pool.query(
        `INSERT INTO company (Name_company) VALUES ('${company}') `
      );

      const inrelcompany = await pool.query(
        `INSERT INTO rel_company_user (ID_company, ID_user) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ${id})`
      );

      return res.json({
        code: 200,
        message: "todo bien... todo correcto y yo que me alegro",
        password,
      });
    } else {
      return res.json({
        code: 400,
        message: "Bro hiciste algo mal",
      });
    }
  }
```

That's the right code, I was trying to insert only a id in a table where have 2 foreign keys, and the problem with the 36 is that I was getting my id like a json type.